# How to stop getting current location from onLocationChanged() in another activity on button click in android

Tags: android

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    lat.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
    lon.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "location changed: " + latitude + " " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    insertUser();
}

    public void stopGetLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

In MainActivity.java, I am getting current location from onlocationchaged() and I've written one method named stopGetLocation() to disable thee location listener.

**StartJourney.java**

```
            stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity m=new MainActivity();
                m.stopGetLocation();
                Toast.makeText(StartJourneyActivity.this, "JOURNEY STOPPED",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

In StartJourneyActivity.java, I've created two buttons, one to start MainActivity and another one to stop getting location. But when I try to stopping getting location by calling stopGetLocation() of MainActivity.java, my application closes forcefully.
Please give me solution to stop getting location from another activity on button click.
Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: try with interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not instantiate a activity like that. Make a static method to expose your logic.

Comment: consider making the location manager static as well. though i do not think static managers are good.

Comment: I tried it already, but it shows errors to 'this' inside the method.

Comment: I've used this inside locationManager.removeUpdates(), thats why it says MainActivity.this cannot be referenced from static context

Comment: use getBaseContext()

Comment: ((MainActivity).getContext()). stopGetLocation(); try that from the other activity. remove any static qualifier from the that method though.